# Java Regular expression betweenStrings

Tags: java, regex

I have a FIle with following kind of input

```
<title>Page title1</title>
<title>Page title2</title>
<title>Page title3</title>
<title>Page title4</title>
<title>Page title5</title>
<title>Page title6</title>
<title>Page title7</title>
<title>Page title8</title>
<title>Page title9</title>
```

I want to extract contents between title
I use this code

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)(<title.*?>)(.+?)(</title>)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
 while (matcher.find()) {
System.out.println(matcher.group().toString());
 }
```

but I get no output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without grouping:

```
(?<=<title>)[^<]*
```

but if it is a valid xml doc, better avoid to parse it with regex.

Comment: Hi. Its not. I tried this regex too, its is still not working..
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=<title>)[^<]*");

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, simply specify which group you want when printing, which for your purposes would be group 2:

```
System.out.println(matcher.group(2).toString());
```

Additionally, considering you get "no output", you should ensure your input string "test" actually contains what you think it does. I recommend this based on the fact that your code does work and it should print the entire match as is.

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern `(?<=<title>).*(?=<\\/title>)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)(<title.*?>)(.+?)(</title>)");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
 while (matcher.find()) 
 {
   System.out.println(matcher.group().toString());
 }
```

Above is very costly operation. you can simply use indexof on string

```
String str="<title>Page title1</title>";
int index=str.indexOf("<title>");
int lastIndex=str.indexOf("</title>");
String literal=str.substring(index+5,lastIndex);
```